# Jquery - fadeIn() displaying same image repeatedly

Tags: jquery, html

I am new on this forum and maybe this question has been asked already. But still, I need help from respected users of this forum. let me share my(HTML n Jquery) coding...

**jquery**

```
      $(".container").click(function(){

        $(".product-view").fadeIn()
      });
      $(".close-button").click(function(){
        $(".product-view").fadeOut()
      });

  </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "middle">
        <img src = "BLUE(Linen Shirt).jpg"> </div>
    <div class="on-top">
        <button class="qvbtn"><b>Quick View</b></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="close-button"> X </div>
    <div class="product-big-image">
        <img src="BLUE(Linen Shirt).jpg"> 
    </div>
    <div class="product-big-desc">
        <h2>Linen Shirt</h2>
        <h5>Produce Code:</h5> 
        <h5>Brand:</h5>
        <div class="price">
            <h4 class="OldPrice"><del>150 SAR</del>
                <sup>50% off</sup>
            </h4> <!--h4 class="NewPrice">75 SAR</h4-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: my question is when i click on quick view button it display same information for all other products. Eg:

Comment: for ex: image1 is apparels image2: trousers and image3 for footwear

Comment: append your HTML

Comment: Thanks shabani, i am getting error while sharing code by too long characters

Comment: plz sharing code in a comment. I update it for you.

Comment: <div class = "container">
                    <div class = "middle">
                      <img src = "BLUE(Linen Shirt).jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="on-top">              
                      <button class="qvbtn"><b>Quick View</b></button>                  
                    </div>
      </div>

Comment: <div class="product-view">
              <div class="close-button"> X </div>
              <div class="product-big-image">
                <img src="BLUE(Linen Shirt).jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="product-big-desc">
                <h2>Linen Shirt</h2>
                <h5>Produce Code:</h5>
                <h5>Brand:</h5>
                <div class="price">
                  <h4 class="OldPrice"><del>150 SAR</del> <sup>50% off</sup></h4>
                  <!--h4 class="NewPrice">75 SAR</h4--></div></div>

Comment: Once again Thanks Shabani..

Answer (score 0):

At first, Do not display div contain image .and after click button display it

```
 <div class="product-view" style="display: none">
```

```js
 $("#btnClick").click(function(){
        $(".product-view").fadeIn()
    });
    $(".close-button").click(function(){
        $(".product-view").fadeOut()
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = "container">
  <div class = "middle">
    <img src = "1g.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="on-top">
    <button id="btnClick" class="qvbtn"><b>Quick View</b></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-view" style="display: none">
  <div class="close-button"> X </div>
  <div class="product-big-image">
    <img src="1.jpg" >
  </div>
  <div class="product-big-desc">
    <h2>Linen Shirt</h2>
    <h5>Produce Code:</h5>
    <h5>Brand:</h5>
    <div class="price">
      <h4 class="OldPrice"><del>150 SAR</del>
        <sup>50% off</sup>
      </h4> <!--h4 class="NewPrice">75 SAR</h4-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied and paste your code but no output, anyways i used display: none in my CSS, please have a look                                                   .product-view{
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #eee;
}

Comment: So now. Your problem is not jquery. Your problem with CSS and HTML. can you send your complete code to my email

Comment: Sure No problem, let me know your email

Comment: pedramham1@gmal.com

Comment: Thanks, Please find my attachment

Comment: plz, check your email. One of the problems your code was that The names of your classes were the same. For your code, you should use a different id for each DIV